# How do I filter on 5 parameters, including a dropdown list using filter expression?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controlparameter

I'm trying to filter my gridview with 5 different parameters.  I can get it to work fine but the issue arises when I add the "All" into the dropdownlist. If I select All in the dropdownlist I can't filter anymore.  It will show the results for everything but filtering doesn't work.  Is there something wrong in my filter expression or control parameter?

This is my current dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
DataTextField="Tab" DataValueField="Tab" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
<asp:ListItem Value="">All</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Tr">Tr</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Out">Out</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="In">In</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This is my source for the filtering:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Log ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC" 
FilterExpression="Com LIKE '%{0}%' AND Usr LIKE '%{1}%' 
AND Tab = '{2}' AND TimeStamp >= '#{3}#' AND TimeStamp <= '#{4}#'">
<FilterParameters> 
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TB1" Name="Com" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" 
ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />

<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TB2" Name="Usr" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" 
ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />   

<asp:ControlParameter Name="Tab" ControlID="DDL1" 
PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>

<asp:ControlParameter Name="Date" ControlID="DateFrom" Type="DateTime" PropertyName="Text"
ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />

<asp:ControlParameter Name="Date" ControlID="DateTo" Type="DateTime"   
PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
    </FilterParameters> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: <asp:ListItem Value="">All</asp:ListItem> shows me something that your SelectedValue is empty when you select ALL and onvertEmptyStringToNull="true" is converting to NULL. When you have NULL I don't think it will work as a string 'NULL' instead it will search for records with 'NULL' value but not NULL.

Comment: I've tried making it false as well and it didn't work either.  Still trying to figure out what I need to modify in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Value of your ALL option in dropdown list

```
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">All</asp:ListItem>
```

Update your control parameter setting default value and removing ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="Tab" ControlID="DDL1" 
PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" DefaultValue="-1"/>
```

Update your filter expression for ***Tab***

```
FilterExpression="Com LIKE '%{0}%' AND Usr LIKE '%{1}%' 
AND (Tab = '{2}' or '{2}' = '-1') AND TimeStamp >= '#{3}#' AND TimeStamp <= '#{4}#'">
```